# javascript hash tables problem

Tags: javascript, hashtable, prototypejs

I'm trying to add markers to a google maps by iterating through a list and retrieving some information. I'm using the prototype library. The code is the following:

```
    var point = new Array();
    var myMarkerOptions = new Array();
    var marker = new Array();

    recommendedList.each(function(item){
        point[item.location.ID] = new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.lat, item.location.lng);
        myMarkerOptions[item.location.ID] = {
              position: point[item.location.ID], 
              map: map
            };
        marker[item.location.ID] = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOption[item.location.ID]);    
        });
```

where the recommendedList is a JSON response of the form:

```
[
 {"artist":"artist1","location":{"lat":"50.952226","lng":"5.34832","ID":28}},
 {"artist":"artist2","location":{"lat":"52.362287","lng":"4.883965","ID":32}},
 ...
]
```

However, this is not working.
I know that the problem is not about the JSON or the google map, because I tried a simpler version with the following code and it worked:

```
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(recommendedList[0].location.lat,recommendedList[0].location.lng);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng, 
          map: map
      });
```

So the problem must be in the iteration and the hash maps.
Anyone can see the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? If you tell us, we might actually be able to help you (instead of making (more or less) educated guesses).

Comment: Why are you using an array instead of an object?

Comment: Have you stepped through the loop with a debugger and confirmed the `recommendedList` is being traversed as expected?

Comment: Also, why do you say you're using a [Hash](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Hash/) and then use an [Array](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough to test without the .each

```
for (var i=0, item; item = recommendedList[i]; i++) {
    point[item.location.ID] = new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.lat, item.location.lng);
    myMarkerOptions[item.location.ID] = {
        position: point[item.location.ID], 
        map: map
    };
    marker[item.location.ID] = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOption[item.location.ID]);    
}
```

You can also simplify this quite a lot, unless you "need" those other arrays:

```
for (var i=0, item; item = recommendedList[i]; i++) {
    marker[item.location.ID] = new google.maps.Marker({
      new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.lat, item.location.lng),
      map
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting method to iterate an array. Does this work in PHP, too?

Comment: @Jitamaro The for loop combines an iterator with testing whether array[i] exists and assigning it to item.  In PHP I would use foreach, which basically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the array accessors you're using. What are you doing the `point`, `myMarkerOptions` and `marker` arrays once you're done with them?

Can you try declaring them as

```
var point = {};
var myMarkerOptions = {};
var marker = {};
```

That'll let you refer to them as `point[item.location.ID]` (etc). I think with the `item.ID` property being a number, JS is trying to set that numeric index of the array, rather than creating a new property in your hash.

Comment: I thought the same thing (see my comment on his question) but then I remembered that he's using the `prototype` framework.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda remember prototype doing odd things to array and/or string prototype to introduce new methods. Doesn't smell right though, it's worth a shot :-)

Comment: Can you clarify the effect of declaring the objects with the syntax: var point = {}; Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype each iterator doesn't support JSON or object data type.